# Unable to update to Wordpress 5.7.2: Could not copy file

Tags: centos, centos7, wordpress, selinux

I'm trying to update to the latest (5.7.2) version of Wordpress from a fresh installation on CentOS 7, however I keep getting the error message

```
Could not copy file.: wp-admin/images/about-color-palette-vert.svg
```

This file is a new file added in 5.7.2 which does not exist in my current version.

The entire contents of `/var/www/html` is owned by `apache:apache` and even with everything set to 777 I still get this error message. Yes, I read the old questions on this. Even Wordpress itself thinks that its file permissions are correct!

I'm using PHP 7.4.19 and Apache 2.4.6. SELinux is enabled. Wordpress is running behind a proxy server which also handles SSL termination. Wordpress can perform loopback requests through the proxy and site health is good, barring warnings about updates.

Answer (score 0):

As with many things CentOS, SELinux is the culprit! It blocks the `httpd` user from writing anything to the file system be default. This can be change with the following command

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/ -R
```

which allows the `httpd` user (in my case, `apache`) to read and write files in `/var/www/html`, and allows Wordpress to update itself.

Comment: You should make sure you restore the original permissions so that your system's security is not compromised.